# error 'the source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt'

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I am attempting to `install nektar++` onto my mac following the `nektar++` installation guide https://doc.nektar.info/userguide/latest/user-guidese3.html#x7-60001.3.

However when I attempt to build the `nektar++` program I encounter an error.

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/dauoodtariq" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
 Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI
```

I have completed the prerequisites and have installed `Xcode CMake BLAS LAPACK Boost TinyXML`

Scotch using the terminal

I have downloaded the tarball and unpacked it.

Then I build the subdirectory and enter it

```
mkdir -p build && cd build
```

But when entering into the terminal

```
ccmake ../
```

I encounter an error.

Comment: Seems you forgot to follow that step - "Change into the nektar++ source code directory" - before `mkdir` one.